# Hive Columnar Loader in HDP2.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using HDP 2.0 and running a simple Pig Script.

I have registered the below jars and I am then executing the below code (updated the schema) -

```
 register /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
       register /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.11.0.2.0.5.0-67.jar;
       register /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec-0.11.0.2.0.5.0-67.jar;

       A = LOAD '/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/hivetables' USING        
       org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.HiveColumnarLoader('id int, name string,age   
       int,create_dt string,timestamp string,accno int');

       F = FILTER A BY (id == 85986249 );

       STORE F INTO '/user/test/Pigout' USING PigStorage();
```

The problem is , Though the value for F is available in the Hive table, the result always writes 0 records into the output. But it is able to load all the records into A.

Basically the Filter function is not working. My Hive table is not partitioned. I beleive that the problem could be in HiveColumarLoade but not able to figure out what it is.

Please let me know if you are aware of a solution. I am struggling a lot with this.

Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: what is the complete schema of the table you are loading? please post it.

Comment: Hi, I have posted the schema also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [pig 0.12 documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/HiveColumnarLoader.html) HiveColumnarLoader appears to require an intermediate relation before you can filter on a non-partition value. Given that id is not a partition that appears to be your problem.

try this:

```
A = LOAD '/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/hivetables' USING        
       org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.HiveColumnarLoader('id int, name string,age   
       int,create_dt string,timestamp string,accno int');

B = FOREACH GENERATE A.id, A.name, A.age, A.create_dt, A.timestamp, A.accno;

F = FILTER A BY (id == 85986249 );

       STORE F INTO '/user/test/Pigout' USING PigStorage();
```

The documentation all seems to say that for processing the actual values you need intermediate relation B.